# Json to table php empty records

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I want display json output to html table, but the table have much empty records. (photo below)

```
<?php
$json2=file_get_contents("****" . $row["Kenteken2"]);
$data2 =  json_decode($json2);

     if (strpos($data2[0], 'model') !== false) {
     echo '<h4>Zelfde serie voertuigen</h4>';
    // Open the table
     echo '<table class="GeneratedTable">';
     echo '<thead><tr><th>Niet DB</th><th>In DB</th></tr></thead><tbody><col style="width:50%" span="2" />';

    // Cycle through the array
                
    foreach ($data2 as $vrt) {
        

        // Output a row
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="/****.php?ktk='.$vrt->model.'&via=ktk.net/'.$row["Kenteken2"].'&model='.$row["MerkModel"].'" target="_blank">'.$vrt->model .'</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="/****.php?ID='.$vrt->id.'">'.$vrt->model2 .'</a> '.$vrt->dienst . ' ' . $vrt->bijzonderheden .'</td>';
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    // Close the table
     echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

?>

result:

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on the question? I'm not actually sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that between the rows <td> have empty rows. This empty rows i want deleted.

Comment: You see under header 'Niet DB' have empty rows when have value at 'In DB'. this empty rows i want to be deleted in the table. That all text is nice together.

Comment: So you want one column listing top to bottom the values that are in the database and one column listing the values that aren't, and you don't care that means a row will consist of two records that don't have anything to do with each other?

Comment: Sorry, i want 2 colums. But without the empty rows inside.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 1 table:

I would create a foreach to create 2 different arrays $neit_db[] and $in_db[]
I would then do a while loop so that until both arrays are empty, I would ping pong between both of them $neit_db[0], then $in_db[0] for each 'row', etc.

If you want 2 tables:

I would create a foreach to create 2 different arrays $neit_db[] and $in_db[]
I would while loop to loop through each array individually for each table that you've put next to each other.